# Python Selenium EC wait (without specifying By.Identifier)

Tags: python, selenium

I think most people know how to wait for an element ie something like this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "myDynamicElement"))
)
element.click()
```

My question is how can I go about abstracting out telling it exactly how I'll give it the element (the "By.ID" piece in the example above.)
That way I can put it as a base class call it anywhere, and hand it any identified element.

Has anyone done something like this?

Answer (score 0):

If you just use css selectors (`#id` for id) you could just always have it use css.

Alternatively, you could always store selectors as a tuple of `(By, locator)` or list `[By, locator]` and splat those

```
locator_tuple = (By.ID, "myDynamicElement")

def wait_method(locator):
    return WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(*locator))
```